# unserialize() problem in php when serialize() works just fine

Tags: php, serialization

I'm using the `serialize()`/`unserialize()` functions in php 5.2. The text to be stored is POSTed via a form. Btw, no white-space before or after. Even if the text contains `"` or `'`, it serializes successfully. The problem is it does not `unserialize()` back. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you ding that? Why not use sessions or such? - Sending data out and receiving it via POST means the user can change it and has to transfer more data back and forth.

Comment: all data are stored in files in serialized format. SESSIONS does not cut it.

Comment: Well let me get it straight. You receive some data from the POST form, then do serialize $_POST array and write resulting string in a file? And then you read it back, the data doesn't unserialize. Right?

Comment: if data contains " or ', yes.

Comment: can you print_r($_POST) to show whats actually being received??

Answer (score 10):

David Walsh has a simple solution:

```
//to safely serialize  
$encoded_serialized_string = base64_encode(serialize($your_array));  

//to unserialize  
$array_restored = unserialize(base64_decode($encoded_serialized_string));
```

http://davidwalsh.name/php-serialize-unserialize-issues

Comment: It works! But I'd like to know if it will be fixed on a later PHP version and what are the origins of this problem.

Comment: This isn't a bug with PHP. As the later answers suggest, you should use addslashes to ensure your quotes are escaped. David Walsh's solution works because it converts everything to a base64 string containing no quotes.

I have personally used this method when I needed to persist stdClass objects to flat files when developing on a system without magic quotes enabled and deploying to a server that did.

Answer (score 4):

It is magic quotes probably in response for such a behavior.
So, to unserialize you may have to do a `stripslashes()` first:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $data = stripslashes($data);
```

though it's almost impossible to have magic quotes on a 5.2 system...
To say something certain, you have to find a difference between initial and returned data.

But anyway, why don't you use sessions instead of sending data to the browser and back? Sessions are a faster and secure way.

Comment: i'm sorry i forgot to tell that text to be serialized is ARRAY_ASSOCIATIVE. (probably) because of this STRIPSLASHES function does not work.

Comment: all data are stored in files in serialized format. SESSIONS does not cut it.

Comment: I'm sorry @Kurt, but stripslashes has NOTHING to do with arrays. It works with strings. And it always works. Anyway, magic quotes is gust a guess, and to tell you something certain, you have to find a difference between initial and returned data. Or at least bring both strings here

Comment: magic quotes is on. when i do print_r data is correct (i mean initial data and returned data is the same). but when unserialize that does not work.

Comment: @Kurt if returned data is the same, serialize **would** work. Period. You have to watch better.

Comment: serialize is working unserialize is not. i know it's strange.

Comment: most likely it's because magic quotes, if you admit it's on. At least you have to realize that noone can fo your job for you. Try to do somethiung sensible, not just repeat the same "not working"

Comment: it's over because there is no real explanation. i just answered to be sensible because you tried hard to help me. (you write "serialize would work" and i said it works). thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

When you serialize, you should use **[`addslashes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)** and when you unserialize, use **[`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)** function.

**Example:**

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
  serialize($variable);
}
else
{
  addslashes(serialize($variable));
}

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
  stripslashes(unserialize($variable));
}
else
{
  unserialize($variable);
}
```

Comment: @Kurt: You might have magic quotes turned on, see my updated answer. Also what error do you get if any?

Comment: Look, @Web. Why don't you run your code before post it? The OP told you it didnt serialize at all. that's true. If you have not enough experience to write  code on the fly - just run it before post and see if it does something or not.

Answer (score -1):

Adding slashes to quotes solves the problem. Have a look at my code:
http://codepad.org/7JWa2BT6

Comment: Wrong comment. I had escaped the variables before forming the array hence adding slashes worked. The serialized string should be escaped. not the reverse